# How to Order Material for: Gravel Driveway With Smooth Stones & Bricks

Tags: brick, driveway, stone, gravel

I am replacing a garden at the end of my driveway with a place to park my truck. We are barefoot a lot so jagged gravel is not ideal. It's fairly level as is but I will level it a bit more. Also the HOA doesn't allow for "gravel" driveway but I can get away with decorative stone, as such looking at "[rough](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Vigoro-0-5-cu-ft-Bagged-Pond-Pebble-Landscape-Rock-54249V/100550970)" or "[smooth](https://www.homedepot.com/p/MSI-Dorado-0-4-cu-ft-1-in-to-2-in-Yellow-Beach-Pebbles-30-lbs-Bag-LHDPEBMDOR5PB/317924230)" options.

ANYWAY... I am trying to figure out the best way to order the layers to get the best traction/wearability while still looking good. My thoughts were to lay the material in this order:

- Ground (bottom)
- Weed Block
- Crushed Aggregate
- Decorative Stone / Bricks (same level, sand under bricks)

I'm wondering though if I should put the aggregate UNDER the weed block for better errosion resitance in the soil and a better "Grab"... worried the week block will allow for slippage over time since the aggregate isn't integrated with the soil.

Also since my truck will rut out the decorative stones, I am going to place bricks in a decorative pattern with space between so the truck ideally deosn't even kick the stone but rolls over the brick for the most part. Is there anyway to keep these in place or is this a terrible idea? Picture below:

[image]

And here is the space:

[image]

**EDIT**

Per the comments I will replace the Weed Block with one of these two GeoTextiles:

[Geotextile 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08XQPBCWM) | [Geotextile 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09TKZC2NS)

Comment: Weed block - doesn't. You want geotextile (not weed block) under your stone to keep it from vanishing into the dirt underneath. It's fairly standard in modern "dirt roads" and does not cause slippage.

Comment: Good call, I edited the question with 2 options I found. Would you suggest the "cloth" type or the "plastic" type (my uneducated observation).

Also if I did this, would I still put aggregate under the smooth stone?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your question is.

Comment: @FreeMan - There were 2 but ecnerwal answered the first (order of underlayment for smooth stone parking space).  The 2nd question is if can I stagger the brigs in river rock and drive over them (see above picture)? I really want a smooth stone parking space and if there is advice on how to achieve it if possible that would be awesome. If I'm missing something obvious I'd like to know.

Comment: I don't think bricks spaced apart will work very well. Any reason you can't have bricks-in-sand with the bricks right next to each other?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I could, but I just worry then as the truck drives over it they will continue to stagger and the lack of "level" bricks will be very obvious considering they are right next to each other and it's frankly cheaper. But if I have to I will... can I just do two strips of bricks for the tires and the rest smooth stone?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact could I just use these: https://www.homedepot.com/p/16-in-x-16-in-x-1-75-in-Pewter-Brickface-Square-Concrete-Step-Stone-72660/100586303

Comment: Yes, you can use those sort of brick/paver things instead of actual bricks.  Pavers will often be thinner than regular bricks, though the thinnest are considered more for walkways than for driveways. Yes, you can do two strips of bricks (or pavers) for the tires and gravel or other stone in between and outside. A large area (a bit tougher with strips for just the tires) in sufficient sand should be quite stable.

Answer (score 2):

In order, going down:

- Pavers (probably want 2.5" thick for a driveway), with polymeric sand in the joints after laying.  Pavers are usually actually concrete, not (clay) brick.  No intentional space between the pavers.
- Sand bedding layer, 0.5-1.0"
- Geotextile
- Gravel (sharp-edged—not
  rounded—either #57 stone or crusher run), 8-12" thick depending how soft your subgrade is. Compact as you can.
- Geotextile
- Subgrade (bare earth, compacted if you
  loosened it when excavating).  You'll want to remove all topsoil and organic material; not clear if that's done in your pic.

Comment: This is great! Based on feedback I think I am moving away from bricks and going to use a gravel grid with slightly smoother stone (see link) -- If I did this, would the geogrid go over or under the sharp-edge gravel base?  : https://www.amazon.com/BaseCore-Geocell-Stabilizer-Perfect-Pathways/dp/B08XB95PRY

Comment: Do not recommend round pebbles for a wear surface.  They do not stay in place.  Unless you like finding them nearby and are willing to "top off" periodically.  You could consider a geogrid with a grass surface if you can find a grass that grows in shade.